# save() on a model instance not update the changed field on related model side

Tags: django, django-models

My models:

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Requisition(models.Model):
    from_inventoryitem = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Assuming that requisition has an OneToMany relation with inventory_item below, and the initial value of inventory_item.quantity is 0, When I excute:

```
>>> requisition = Requisition.objects.get(id=1)
>>> requisition.from_inventoryitem.quantity = 500
>>> requisition.save()

>>> requisition.from_inventoryitem.quantity
500
>>> inventory_item.quantity
0

>>> requisition.from_inventoryitem == inventory_item
True
```

The inventory_item.quantity in database and InventoryItem side is still 0.
How can I update that change to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. You have to save each instance seperately. `requisition.from_inventoryitem` actually queries the InventoryItem instance from the database, just to set the quantity.

```
requisition = Requisition.objects.get(id=1)
requisition.from_inventoryitem.quantity = 500 # this generates another query here!
requisition.from_inventoryitem.save()
```

or even better, with a single query, single save

```
inv_item = InventoryItem.objects.get(requisition_set__id=1)
inv_item.quantity = 500
inv_item.save()
```

best way. single database call:

```
InventoryItem.objects.filter(requisition_set__id=1).update(quantity=500)
```